# why does mercurial try to reach to the svn root when converting?

Tags: svn, ubuntu, mercurial

I am trying to convert a svn project to a mercurial project. I am using mercurial 2.1.2, my svn client is 1.6.12, and there is python 2.7.2 on an Ubuntu 11.10 operating system.

I have read/write access on my example repo : **http://svn.companyname.com**/projectname/Server/.

When I try to convert this repo using :

```
hg convert -s svn http://svn.pozitron.com/DubaiFirst/Server/trunk
```

I get the following error :

```
abort: log stream exception '("Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS request for '**http://svn.companyname.com**'", 175002)'
```

See that Url is company svn root and I dont have access to it. So I want to know why mercurial tries to reach the root of svn tree? And is there anything that I can do to prevent it from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the why, but can you use `svnsync` to mirror the the portion of the repository you want to convert locally?  I've seen a lot of recommendations to svnsync to local before converting anyway since the conversion process is very chatty and really benefits from local access to the repo -- also it makes trying again less painful since one always always redoes the convert a few times before getting the options exactly as one wants them (`--filemap, --branchmap, --authormap, etc.).

Comment: svnsync downloads all the specified portion of the repo and does that using http. it is a looong process. but anyway, thanks for the answer ;) (we managed to convert the same repo using, hg 1.4.1!!! )

Comment: You should only have to do it once anyway.  Glad you got it going.